# Issue with Sync in a Terminal Server\Citrix Published Application

Tags: microsoft-edge, citrix, terminal-server

Published applications can't open Universal Windows Applications (UWA). Edge has changed the authentication to a UWA method for sync authentication.  Given this we cannot get Sync to work as we cannot authenticate. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the application is a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app? Whether this issue only occurs in Microsoft Edge browser? Before published the application, whether it works well? Try to check your code and the logic, make sure it not detect the browser and change authentication method, in my opinion, generally the Edge browser will not change the authentication method.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT UWP has a dependency on explorer.exe which is not running in the user's session. I think the issue here is that an authentication dialog which is popped up from Edge has a UWP based dialog...